# MySQL insert - for each row, return insert id

Tags: mysql, cursor, bulkinsert, last-insert-id

Let's say I have an array of data to insert. I'm going to have an insert that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`name`, `value`) VALUES('name1','value1'),('name2','value2')
```

We're assuming that `table` has a primary key.

Is there a way to, while batch inserting like this, grab the last insert id for each row, and return the those new ids? I know you can't do this traditionally with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, but I'm wondering if I could use something like a cursor to achieve this functionality, and maybe a temporary table to store the values until I return them.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

```
LAST_INSERT_ID() will return the first id from a multi row insert.
```

So you can just return that value and:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`name`, `value`) VALUES('name1','value1'),('name2','value2');

SET @firstid := LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT * from table1 where id>=@firstid;
```

Comment: I've seen solutions similar to this in a few places. The thing I'm worried about is non-incremental primary keys (i.e. other requests inserting rows at the same time)

Comment: there is no same time while transaction.  if you do `INSERT` that is one command - there is no case when it is not consecutive